# ASPX page to return http 500 error message regardless of Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have a lot of Ajax calls that connect to ASPX page instead of Web Methods (I don't have control over that).

It happens sometimes that I call an ASPX with the wrong arguments, and a HTTP 500 is throw (this is what I want). But in some cases, I really need to get the message of the error, so I can handle it in my javascript UI.

Problem is : I don't have control over the Web.Config, because my application can be use on multiple server. So the people configuring the Web.Config can do whatever they want, like forwarding a HTTP 500...

So is there a neat way to be sure that my UI will always get the error message, regardless of the Web.Config?

Comment: so you know, you've got http 500 error and you also know what method you called. so why don't you simply show this message "error occured. Correct way of calling this method is with below arguments". I mean if wrong arguments you pass, is all the problem you have.

Comment: If I don't have the choice, that what I'll do. But my method is more complex than that, so I want to be more specific with my users, and tell them why this error happened.

Comment: but that's how you're most specific. Instead of telling them what they passed is wrong, tell them what to pass exactly. that way you also tell them they did something wrong with the arguments.

Comment: I already have some validation in the UI, so the users can't put any value they want. But my method is more complex than just simple arguments. They can, for instance, pass a well formated XML file, but with some data that doesn't make sense for the server. It would be a lot of job to do all validation in the UI, and it is just not possible for performance issue.

Comment: Confused - what exactly do you control? The Web service or are you just consuming some other (3rd party) web service? Seems you need to clarify - re: if you control the web service you can control responses (http response code, error messages, etc.).

Comment: I'm developing the application. So I have control on all the code. But for design reasons, we don't use Web Services. We are calling ASPX pages instead (ajax call). But, the application can be install on any server, so the users can put whatever they want in the Web.Config, including redirection of http 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you end up with the same problem then me, and especially if you don't use a recent version of ASP.NET, you can always create your own way to pass errors.

This means that the server won't return an HTTP 500, but a HTTP 200 instead with a json inside that tell your client about the problem that happened. But then, $.ajax or any other libraries won't understand that, so you'll have to handle error case yourself. This is dirty, so don't o that unless you really don't have the choice.